# $f:(X,\mathcal T)\to (Y,\mathcal S)$ is continuous on a compact Hausdorff space, is $f^{-1}(\mathcal S)$ a subbase for $\mathcal T$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a compact and Hausdorff topological space. $(Y,\mathcal S)$ be a topological space, and $f:X\to Y$ be continuous. Is the topology generated by $f^{-1}(\mathcal S)$ the same as $\mathcal T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is not injective, the topology $\tau$ generated by $\{f^{-1}[S]:S\in\mathscr{S}\}$ cannot be the same as $\mathscr{T}$. To see this, let $x,y\in X$ be such that $f(x)=f(y)$, but $x\ne y$. Then for each $U\in\tau$, either $\{x,y\}\subseteq U$, or $\{x,y\}\cap U=\varnothing$, but there are $U,V\in\mathscr{T}$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

Comment: How if $f$ is injective?

Comment: @CutieKrait: You still can’t guarantee anything: let $Y=X$ and $\mathscr{S}=\{\varnothing,X\}$, as in Arthur’s answer, and let $f:X\to X$ be the identity map. Then $f$ is continuous, and $\tau\ne\mathscr{T}$.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  If $Y$ is an indiscrete (trivial) space (*i.e.*, $\mathcal{S} = \{ \varnothing , Y \}$), then $f^{-1} ( \mathcal{S} ) = \{ \varnothing , X \}$ is the indiscrete topology on $X$, and is not Hausdorff (unless $|X| = 1$).  (Note that any function into an indiscrete space is continuous.)